# Find all primes $p$ such that $z$ is also a prime number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. We know that $z=(-√3+2)^{2^{p-2}}+(√3+2)^{2^{p-2}}$ is an integer.

My question is: Find all primes $p$ such that $z$ is also a prime number.

Comment: I can see you trying to evaluate $\mathbb R$eally complicated expressions

Comment: @DigitalBrain: Yes, I am trying this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one of your previous questions, using the binominal theorem, for $p\ge 3$ we have:
$$z={2\cdot ∑_{j=0}^{2^{p-3}}\binom{2^{p-2}}{2j}2^{2^{p-2}-2j} 3^{j}}$$
And since the sum involved is greater than $1$, $z$ cant be prime. For $p=2$ we have $z=4$ and therefore, there are no such primes $p$.